# Sass Syntax Error: wrong number of arguments (1 for 3) for `rgb'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I use Ruby On Rails 5 and gem sass-rails 5.0

For some reason I get an error message:

> wrong number of arguments (1 for 3) for `rgb'

in line number 2 of file app/assets/stylesheets/main.css.scss

```
$main-color-raw: rgb(0,80,170);
$main-color: rgb($main-color-raw);
$main-color-bright: rgba($main-color-raw, 0.5);
```

I tried with a hex color value instead of rgb():

```
$main-color-raw: #0050aa;
```

But get the same error message.

It looks like the sass-variable $main-color-raw is not evaluated correctly and maybe is the rails-sass gem configuration wrong.

So I added in my config/application.rb

```
config.sass.preferred_syntax = :scss
config.sass.line_comments = false
config.sass.cache = false
```

from the rails-sass github documentation page.

But still the same error.

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$main-color-raw: rgb(0,80,170);
```

so in `$main-color`, you've got:

```
$main-color: rgb(rgb(0,80,170));
```

so you are passing only 1 argument to rgb.

You should declare main-color-raw as:

```
$main-color-raw: 0, 80, 170;
```

Comment: thank you @nuaky, that was it! I feel uncomfortable to declare a variable with multiple comma separated values so I used $main-color: $main-color-raw; instead